# Merge documents into single document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How do I go about using mongodb aggregation pipeline to get the end result?

I have the following documents

```
{ 
    "_id" : "aaa", 
    "Count" : 137.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : "bbb", 
    "Count" : 11.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : "ccc", 
    "Count" : 236.0
}
```

I need to merge them into a single document that looks like this..

```
{
    aaa: 137,
    bbb: 11,
    ccc: 236
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change key document mongodb aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280829/change-key-document-mongodb-aggregate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

Use `$arrayToObject` to convert the arrays with value into object followed by `$mergeObjects` to merge all the documents into single document.

`$replaceRoot` to promote the results as top.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "results":{"$mergeObjects":{"$arrayToObject":[[["$_id","$Count"]]]}}
  }},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$results"}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you @Veeram! It works. Got a question though - why nest the array two levels deep?

Comment: You are welcome. `$arrayToObject` takes an array of two-element arrays